# Recursion in frontend compilation - how to analyze and debug this?

Tags: vaadin

I did a few changes to my Vaadin based application and now I am getting the below frontend compilation error when trying to start up the application.

That output doesn't give me the slightest clue as to what might be wrong here. None of the classes or files involved seem to stem from my application. What is this "VaadinDevmodeGizmo" anyway?
How does one debug or analyze this???

Any hint or support would be highly appreciated!

```
------------------ Starting Frontend compilation. ------------------
[0m2021-06-03 23:15:34,823 DEBUG [task-2] com.vaadin.flow.server.DevModeHandler: 
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe \ 
    .\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\bin\webpack-dev-server.js \ 
    --config \ 
    .\webpack.config.js --port 58180 \ 
    --watchDogPort=58179 -d --inline=false 

2021-06-03 23:15:34,831 INFO  [task-2] com.vaadin.flow.server.DevModeHandler: Running webpack to compile frontend resources. This may take a moment, please stand by...
2021-06-03 23:15:34,862 INFO  [http-nio-8080-exec-2] com.vaadin.flow.server.DefaultDeploymentConfiguration: 
Vaadin is running in DEBUG MODE.
When deploying application for production, remember to disable debug features. See more from https://vaadin.com/docs/
Using Vaadin 15+ bootstrap mode.
 'index.html' is not found from 'D:\Projects\my_app\frontend\index.html'.
Generating a default one in 'target/index.html'. Move it to the 'D:\Projects\my_app\frontend' folder if you want to customize it.
 'index.ts' is not found from 'D:\Projects\my_app\frontend\index.ts'.
Generating a default one in 'target/index.ts'. Move it to the 'D:\Projects\my_app\frontend' folder if you want to customize it.
2021-06-03 23:15:35,974 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-2] com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.PushRequestHandler: Using pre-initialized Atmosphere for servlet springServlet
2021-06-03 23:15:35,978 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-2] com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServletService: Using 'com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.IndexHtmlRequestHandler' in client mode bootstrapping
2021-06-03 23:15:35,982 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-2] com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinService: The application has the following routes: 
2021-06-03 23:15:35,990 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-2] java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef: RouteData{parentLayout=class my_app.ui.MainLayout, url='', parameters={}, navigationTarget=class my_app.ui.views.apps.EntryView, routeAliases=[]}
2021-06-03 23:15:35,990 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-2] java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef: RouteData{parentLayout=class my_app.ui.MainLayout, url='application/:___url_parameter*', parameters={___url_parameter=com.vaadin.flow.router.RouteParameterData@27361303}, navigationTarget=class my_app.ui.views.apps.ApplicationView, routeAliases=[]}
2021-06-03 23:15:35,990 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-2] java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef: RouteData{parentLayout=null, url='login', parameters={}, navigationTarget=class my_app.ui.views.login.LoginView, routeAliases=[]}
2021-06-03 23:15:35,990 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-2] java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef: RouteData{parentLayout=null, url='tabsheet', parameters={}, navigationTarget=class my_app.ui.views.apps.TabSheetView, routeAliases=[]}

Project is running at http://localhost:58180/webpack-dev-server/
webpack output is served from /VAADIN/
Content not from webpack is served from D:\Projects\my_app\target\classes\META-INF\VAADIN, src/main/webapp
         Serving the 'stats.json' file dynamically.
Hash: 8e0c76d4c08e28550144
Version: webpack 4.42.0
Time: 122ms
Built at: 03.06.2021 23:15:38
     Asset      Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
index.html  2.69 KiB          [emitted]  

ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Recursion in resolving
Stack:
  resolve: (D:\Projects\my_app\frontend) D:\Projects\my_app\target\flow-frontend\VaadinDevmodeGizmo.js
  newResolve: (D:\Projects\my_app\frontend) D:\Projects\my_app\target\flow-frontend\VaadinDevmodeGizmo.js
  parsedResolve: (D:\Projects\my_app\frontend) D:\Projects\my_app\target\flow-frontend\VaadinDevmodeGizmo.js
  describedResolve: (D:\Projects\my_app\frontend) D:\Projects\my_app\target\flow-frontend\VaadinDevmodeGizmo.js
  relative: (D:\Projects\my_app\target\flow-frontend\VaadinDevmodeGizmo.js) 
  describedRelative: (D:\Projects\my_app\target\flow-frontend\VaadinDevmodeGizmo.js) 
  rawFile: (D:\Projects\my_app\target\flow-frontend\VaadinDevmodeGizmo.js) 
  file: (D:\Projects\my_app\target\flow-frontend\VaadinDevmodeGizmo.js) 

ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Recursion in resolving
Stack:
  resolve: (D:\Projects\my_app\frontend) D:\Projects\my_app\target\index
  newResolve: (D:\Projects\my_app\frontend) D:\Projects\my_app\target\index
  parsedResolve: (D:\Projects\my_app\frontend) D:\Projects\my_app\target\index
  describedResolve: (D:\Projects\my_app\frontend) D:\Projects\my_app\target\index
  relative: (D:\Projects\my_app\target\index) 
  describedRelative: (D:\Projects\my_app\target\index) 
  rawFile: (D:\Projects\my_app\target\index) 
  file: (D:\Projects\my_app\target\index) 

ERROR in   Error: Child compilation failed:
  Entry module not found: Error: Recursion in resolving
  Stack:
    resolve: (D:\Projects\my_app\frontend) D:\Proje  cts\my_app\target\index.html
    newResolve: (D:\Projects\my_app\frontend) D:\Pr  ojects\my_app\target\index.html
    parsedResolve: (D:\Projects\my_app\frontend) D:  \Projects\my_app\target\index.html
    describedResolve: (D:\Projects\my_app\frontend)   D:\Projects\my_app\target\index.html
    relative: (D:\Projects\my_app\target\index.html  ) 
    describedRelative: (D:\Projects\my_app\target\i  ndex.html) 
    rawFile: (D:\Projects\my_app\target\index.html)   
    file: (D:\Projects\my_app\target\index.html) :
  Error: Recursion in resolving
  Stack:
    resolve: (D:\Projects\my_app\frontend) D:\Proje  cts\my_app\target\index.html
    newResolve: (D:\Projects\my_app\frontend) D:\Pr  ojects\my_app\target\index.html
    parsedResolve: (D:\Projects\my_app\frontend) D:  \Projects\my_app\target\index.html
    describedResolve: (D:\Projects\my_app\frontend)   D:\Projects\my_app\target\index.html
    relative: (D:\Projects\my_app\target\index.html  ) 
    describedRelative: (D:\Projects\my_app\target\i  ndex.html) 
    rawFile: (D:\Projects\my_app\target\index.html)   
    file: (D:\Projects\my_app\target\index.html)
  
  - compiler.js:79 
    [application]/[3.2.0_webpack@4.42.0]/[html-webpack-plugin]/lib/compiler.js:7    9:16
  
  - Compiler.js:343 
    [application]/[4.42.0_webpack@4.42.0]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:343:11
  
  - Compiler.js:681 
    [application]/[4.42.0_webpack@4.42.0]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:681:15
  
  
  - Hook.js:154 AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook
    [application]/[1.1.3]/[tapable]/lib/Hook.js:154:20
  
  - Compiler.js:678 
    [application]/[4.42.0_webpack@4.42.0]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:678:31
  
  
  - Hook.js:154 AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook
    [application]/[1.1.3]/[tapable]/lib/Hook.js:154:20
  
  - Compilation.js:1423 
    [application]/[4.42.0_webpack@4.42.0]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:1423:35
  
  

Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
    
    ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Recursion in resolving
    Stack:
      resolve: (D:\Projects\my_app\frontend) D:\Projects\my_app\target\index.html
      newResolve: (D:\Projects\my_app\frontend) D:\Projects\my_app\target\index.html
      parsedResolve: (D:\Projects\my_app\frontend) D:\Projects\my_app\target\index.html
      describedResolve: (D:\Projects\my_app\frontend) D:\Projects\my_app\target\index.html
      relative: (D:\Projects\my_app\target\index.html) 
      describedRelative: (D:\Projects\my_app\target\index.html) 
      rawFile: (D:\Projects\my_app\target\index.html) 
      file: (D:\Projects\my_app\target\index.html) 
Failed to compile.
------------------ Frontend compilation failed. ------------------
```

Comment: https://github.com/vaadin/flow/blob/master/flow-client/src/main/frontend/VaadinDevmodeGizmo.ts

Answer (score 1):

The `VaadinDevmodeGizmo` is the live reload widget and should reside in the flow-client jar from where it should be copied to `target/flow-frontend` directory on the prepare-frontend step.
This folder is then linked by (p)npm to `node_modules/@vaadin/flow-frontend` by the dependency `"@vaadin/flow-frontend": "./target/flow-frontend",` in `package.json`.

What I don't get is what is it trying to resolve to get the recursion. Is it resolving `D:\Projects\my_app\frontend` all the time as the rest would seem to be what is expected of the paths.

Do you get any extra information on the execution if you add into `webpack.config.js`

```
{
  stats: {
    logging: 'log'
  }
}
```

Into the `module.exports = merge(flowDefaults,)`
Also try with `verbose` as it might give more info if there is lots of collapsed data.